# abrir um aplicativo nativo android/ios/wp

Tags: android, ios, windows-phone

Consigo abrir um aplicativo com um link web no ios (ex: sms=numero), como faço para abrir no android e windows phone? existe outra maneira de abrir para os 3 OS por html ou algum outro script?

Comment: Bem vindo, quanto mais detalhes e mais específica sua pergunta, maiores são as chances de uma resposta. http://pt.stackoverflow.com/tour

Answer (score 1):

Para poder abrir aplicativos através de links é preciso usar URI Schemes.

O Windows Phone suporta alguns tipos como:

```
<a href="tel:(12) 3456-7890">Abrir discador</a>
```

Neste link você pode encontrar outros exemplos de uso:  http://talkitbr.com/2015/06/11/usando-uri-schemes-no-windows-phone